# Is "Memory 1" in Visual Studio representing machine code/language?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've 3 questions regarding assembly & machine code in Visual Studio.

1. I've been reading about machine code and wondering if the "Memory 1" section in Visual Studio represents machine code? Please see the image below.
2. If "Memory 1" does not represent machine code, is it possible to view machine code in Visual Studio?

**Snippet of Disassembly Section**
*Please refer to the screenshot below for the full image*
--- c:\codes\hello\hello.c -----------------------------------------------------

```
     1: #include<stdio.h>
     2: 
     3: int main()
     4: {
00411380  push        ebp  
00411381  mov         ebp,esp  
00411383  sub         esp,0C0h
```

...

```
     5:     printf("Hello World\n");
0041139E  mov         esi,esp  
004113A0  push        offset string "Hello World\n" (41573Ch)  
004113A5  call        dword ptr [__imp__printf (4182B0h)]  
004113AB  add         esp,4  
004113AE  cmp         esi,esp  
004113B0  call        @ILT+295(__RTC_CheckEsp) (41112Ch)  
     6:     return 0;
004113B5  xor         eax,eax
```

**Snippet of Memory 1 Section**
*Please refer to the screenshot below for the full image*

```
0x00411380  55 8b ec 81 ec c0 00 00  U.ì.ìÀ..
0x00411388  00 53 56 57 8d bd 40 ff  .SVW..@ÿ
0x00411390  ff ff b9 30 00 00 00 b8  ÿÿ.0...¸
```

...

```
0x0041573C  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f  Hello Wo
0x00415744  72 6c 64 0a 00 00 00 00  rld.....
```

3. How to make the uploaded image appear on the stackflow instead of link?
   Example: see below

[See the image of "Memory" in Visual Studio here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m3ZQ.jpg)

Comment: No, the disassembled view at 411380 is "machine code". The stuff at 41473c is data.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton
I thought 411380 & 41473c is the address while the data is on the right side? No?

Comment: The numbers on the left in each view are the addresses. The bytes (whether opcodes or program data, like the string value) are the data at those addresses. That's why I said "at", e.g, "the values stored at the address". The values at 411380 are machine code-opcodes/instructions/whatever. The values at 41573c are data liked the string value, debug info, whatever.

Comment: From what I understand, Disassembly section (middle pane) represents Assembly Language, not Machine Code. Please correct me if I'm wrong.